# Strange interpolation with natual-neighbor method

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I have base shapefile and try to use different interpolation methods to get image like this:

[image: raster]

This layer is constructed using point to raster conversion.

Generally, interpolation methods as idw and so on works normal, but exactly natural neighbor does very strange thing:

[image: nat neighbor res]

Result is veeeeery long image. What can it be?

The 180th meridian goes through my map, may it be the reason?

Comment: Almost undoubtedly. I've seen this before in images that straddle the date line... can you move the image with Shift http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007t000000 then shift it back when done.

Comment: I hope you're very close. But shift tool is for rasters and Natural neighbor wants points layer as argument. Do you mean to use shift tool for points in some way?

Comment: point->raster->shift->point->natural neighbours->shift... there isn't a vector tool for moving features on bulk by a constant. You could try projecting to a spatial reference that uses a different 0, or project to UTM Zone 60 or 1 then project back to geographic.